# How to disable the custom directive action on the first column of the table row?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, custom-directive, angular-directive-link

I have a custom directive which opens the table row related data in a new window. When i click on the first column of the table row which is a checkbox selection, it is opening a new window, how should i avoid the custom directive actions on first column of the table row.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; test: results;" [routerLink]="row" appNewWindow></tr>
```

Comment: appNewWindow is the customdirective and routerLink is the input value to that directive, i want this action to be disabled for the first column of the table row.

Answer (score 0):

Adding or removing directives dynamically is not supported in Angular. Its has to be determined when you are coding your template. For your situation components would be right way.